# Implementing a impulse response involving double summation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement the following impulse response for a filter.[image: Impulse Response Equation]

**When t is constant the output is correct but when it is variable as in the image (from nT to (n+1)T) i am not able to get correct output.**

This is the code i wrote-

```
a=3;
b=4;

H = zeros(1,14);

c=[9 10];

for m=0:2
 for n=0:1
   for t=1:14
    H(t)=H(t)+(c(n+1)*((a*((t-(n*T))/T)+b).^m));
   end
 end  
end

disp(H(4));
```

Comment: You need an `if` statement to check the condition for psi

Comment: Sorry @MadPhysicist i didn't get you.

Comment: psi is either `a * ((t - n * T) / T + b).^m` *or* `0`, depending on whether ` n * T <= t < (n + 1) * T` or not. You don't make that check anywhere.